# Passing Multiple Variables to a PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to pass multiple variables `city1` and `area1` (JavaScript variables) in a URL to a PHP page I but got stuck in on the part shown below. What am I doing wrong?

```
$("#list").load("selectcity.php?city1="+city1&"area1="+area1);
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Comment: Your `&` needs to go inside of quotes: `selectcity.php?city1="+city1"&area1="+area1`

Comment: @AndyJones: the ***PROBLEM*** with the code was that the `&`s were outside of the `"`s!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&` character should be inside quotes and not outside quotes. This is the corrected code :

```
$("#list").load("selectcity.php?city1="+city1+"&area1="+area1);
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

**GET** parameters are separated by the character `&`. You are passing 2 parameters to the file separated by `&`. The `?` sign in the URL indicates that the next characters coming after it is the `GET` parameters.

Or you can use `$.get` which is very easy to set up and works fine like `$.load` :

```
$.get("selectcity.php", {"city1": city1, "area1": area1}, function(response){
 $("#list").html(response);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better not to form query string manually, since you will constantly encounter not-so-notable bugs. jQuery offers a way to construct query string automatically from object:

```
var ajaxData = {
    city1: city1,
    area1: area1
};
$.get('selectcity.php', ajaxData, function(data) {
    $('#list').html(data);
});
```

([jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/))

It requires slightly more code but is guaranteed to be safe. There is also a `.load(url, data)` shortcut, but it will send a POST request instead of GET request, and that's probably not what you want.

Also, i'm not sure jQuery will automatically urlencode manually-formed query strings, so string concatenation approach may introduce even more bugs.